# Alignment issue in table with pdfkit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, node-modules, pdfkit

I am drawing pdf content using PDF KIT. I am able to create the table but I have some alignment issues.

Below is my code

```
async renderPdf(data: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let doc = new PDFDocument();
        doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));
        let x1 = doc.x;
        let x6 = 310;
        doc.rect(doc.x, doc.y - 50, 450, 265).stroke()
            .image('images/test.png', doc.x + 10, doc.y - 40, { width: 60, height: 20 })
            .moveTo(doc.x, doc.y - 10).lineTo(doc.x + 450, doc.y - 10).stroke()
        let x = doc.x
        doc.fillColor('blue', 0.8).text('Basic Information', ((x + 450 / 2) - 50), doc.y, { align: 'justify', width: 100, height: doc.currentLineHeight() })
        doc.moveDown()
        console.log(doc.y)
        doc.fillColor('black').font('Helvetica-Bold').text('Amount Requested', x1, doc.y, { indent: 5,width:200 })
            doc.font('Helvetica').text(data.lead.amountRequested, x6, doc.y)
            .rect(x1, doc.y, 450, 0.2).stroke()
        console.log(doc.y)

        doc.fillColor('black').font('Helvetica-Bold').text('Business Start Date', x1, doc.y, { indent: 5 })
            .font('Helvetica').text(data.lead.business.businessStartDate, x6, doc.y)
            .rect(x1, doc.y, 450, 0.2).stroke()
        doc.fillColor('black').font('Helvetica-Bold').text('Leagal Structure', x1, doc.y, { indent: 5 })
            .font('Helvetica').text(data.lead.business.legalStructure, x6, doc.y)
            .rect(x1, doc.y, 450, 0.2).stroke()
        doc.fillColor('black').font('Helvetica-Bold').text('Loan Purpose', x1, doc.y, { indent: 5 })
            .font('Helvetica').text(data.lead.loanPurpose, x6, doc.y)
            .rect(x1, doc.y, 450, 0.2).stroke()
        doc.end()
        resolve(doc)
    })
}
```

**Output of code**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Please tell me how can I achieve the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

It is because `doc.y` is calculated after each .text,
You can use a variable that stores the value for each line `let y1 = doc.y` or using `continued` and you play with the `x` until it is fine e.g.:

```
doc.fillColor('black').font('Helvetica-Bold').text('Business Start Date', x1, doc.y, { indent: 5,continued: true})
        .font('Helvetica').text(Date(), 100, doc.y)
```